# take input from a Variable and store it into same variable but in a diff file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Input file : input.txt

```
l1="R2"
l2="R1"
```

"Another file name : output.sh"

```
l1=""
l2=""
```

I want to copy the value of variables `l1,l2` from input.txt to a file variable `l1,l2` of file output.sh

Comment: As the question is described, the following answer your question: `cp input.txt output.sh` - did I answer your question? if not - please update your question to describe the problem in a better way.

Comment: i am trying that only R2 should stored in the variable l1, the way you told will copy all the contents of input file in output.sh

Comment: I want only the value of variable i.e text between " " to go into another file of same variable

Comment: What is "a file of that variable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to output.sh to accomplish the assignments given in input.txt, you could source the input file

So this would be the content of output.sh

```
l1="" # not needed
l2="" # not needed
source input.txt
```

This produces what you want (a value in l1 of R2):

```
$ cat - > input.txt <<EOF
> l1="R2"
> l2="R1"
> EOF
$ cat - > output.sh <<'EOF'
> l1="" # not needed
> l2="" # not needed
> source input.txt
> echo $l1
> EOF
$ sh output.sh
R2
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: @ShubhamJain in what way? what should it do? What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: after running your soultion , then also my variable value is same as before,there is no value in variable l1

Comment: It works. I've added the shell output that shows that it produces the desired value in l1. Please describe completely what you want to do that this isn't doing or show completely what you are doing that doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it worked for me also now, i was doing it wrong. tysm for help